# How can I transfer items from my iPhone into my iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios

i just formatted my computer a few weeks ago. This week, iTunes suggested I upgrade my iPhone OS to 4.0.2. Ok .. but just before I start the install, i get the following warning:

[image]

So i'm assuming that this means that if i continue (and update the OS) all my purchased (paid and/or free) apps will be gone. AND all my music and movies, etc. ?

I'm not sure how I tell iTunes about my music and movies :(

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the official solution: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1848

Answer (score 0):

Just sync it to your computer via iTunes:

How to sync iphone http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386